# Keep Room database version number during development

Tags: android, android-room

Is it possible to keep the database version number during development? I'm new to Android Dev and Room so I'm building my app piece by piece testing the functionality as I go. As such every time I create a new entity I have to update my database version number.

During development is it possible to set a flag to ignore changes?

So far I've just used `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` when upping the version number, but then I obviously need to make sure I remove this. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to this question is no, there is not. Saying this there is a way to get around this issue. When you do a database change you only need to change the version number which will trigger a migration script - in your case simply destroying the database and creating the new one. When you want to release your product simply reset the version number to the one you require. That way you can continually test but still have reasonable version numbers for your live application.

Hope that helps.